# Configure OpenMPI to run on a single machine (Debian/Linux)

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, multicore, hpc, openmpi

I've installed OpenMPI on my Ubuntu 11.04 machine.

My understanding is that I type `mpirun` and magic happens.

What I don't understand is how to configure `mpirun` to make this magic happen only on my machine's two cores.

How do you configure OpenMPI to run on a single machine using multiple of its cores?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no configuration needed, just pass the "-n 2" option to mpirun and it will start two processes. The [mpirun](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mpirun) documentation provides further information.

Comment: But how does it know which or how many nodes to run on unless it is configured? Is the default configuration a single node? How do you know this? Can you point to a guide?

Comment: @Richard: Without configuration, it uses only localhost. If you want to use multiple nodes, you need to provide a "hostfile", or use a batch scheduler which does it behind the scenes. As for docs, see the mpirun manpage, and the FAQ at http://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=running